# Difference between JNLP and headless method of Jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, qtp, uft14

I am Executing automated QTP/UFT test scripts using Jenkins.

After installing the jenkins slave through JNLP in QTP server and running the automation from jenkins, the slave is getting disconnected and the job is failing with below license error.

`5:34:22 PM Launching QTP Application
C:\AUTOMATION_FRAMEWORK\STARTUP.vbs(33, 1) HP Unified Functional Testing: Neithe
r QTP license nor UFT license is installed, can’t run QTP Automation`

But when I am running the headless mode of jenkins slave in qtp server and run the automation scripts through jenkins , it goes well.

What is the issue here and how it is different while running the same scripts  in JNLP and headless mode of jenkins slave.